# objective-c nsmutablearray setValue forKey issue

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, setvalue

My codes:

```
NSArray *array = //objects here
NSMutableArray *mutarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *s in array)
    {
        NSRange ran = [s rangeOfString:@"abc"];
    if (ran.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        int inde = [array indexOfObject:s];
        [mutarray setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:inde] forKey:s];
    } 
    }
    NSLog (@"mutarray: %@", mutarray);
```

I have tried NSMutableDictionary, but the content is unordered, so I prefer NSMutableArray to store Values and Keys orderly. But the output of NSLog showed nothing, what in the hell?
The output of NSMutableDictionary showed four discoveries.

---

EDIT:

I even tried this code in front of the NSLog, but nothing shows:

```
[mutarray setValue:@"aha" forKey:@"jaha"];
```

---

EDIT:
Guys, thanks for the answer! Now I understand. But the problem is that I store numbers as values and strings as keys. I have an NSMutableDictionary which is unordered. I still havent figured out how I should order it. I have the codes which I use, but it is not properly written:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 intValue];
    int v2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

In other method:

```
NSArray *ordered = [[mutdic allValues] sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
NSLog (@" ordered: %@", ordered);
```

The output shows only:

```
2011-08-29 22:36:03.998 scanner2[32359:207]  ordered: (
    1,
    5,
    9,
    16
)
```

The output should show this in ordered numerically:

```
2011-08-29 22:36:03.992 scanner2[32359:207] mutdic:  5 jam (geologi) en
2011-08-29 22:36:03.993 scanner2[32359:207] mutdic:  9 jax. (geologi)jammen
2011-08-29 22:36:03.994 scanner2[32359:207] mutdic:  1 beta (geologi).
2011-08-29 22:36:03.995 scanner2[32359:207] mutdic: 16 .(geologi),be;ta;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` does not store key/value pairs, it only stores objects.  To add an object to the array, use the `-addObject:` method.

Use an **array** to store an ordered list of objects.  Use a **dictionary** when you need to look up an object given some key.  If you want an ordered list of a dictionary's keys, use

```
NSArray* orderedKeys = 
    [[myDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

**Edit**:  A couple of more options.

1. Just store an array of indexes, then look up the value in your main `array` of strings.

   ```
   for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i)
   {
       NSString* s = [array objectAtIndex:i];
       NSRange ran = [s rangeOfString:@"abc"];
       if (ran.location != NSNotFound)
       {
           [mutarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
       } 
   }

   for (NSNumber* index in mutarray)
   {
       NSLog(@"Found %@:%@", index, [array objectAtIndex:[index intValue]]);
   }
   ```
2. Store a two-dimensional array of indexes and strings:

   ```
   for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i)

   {
       NSString* s = [array objectAtIndex:i];
       NSRange ran = [s rangeOfString:@"abc"];
       if (ran.location != NSNotFound)
       {
           [mutarray addObject:
               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i],
                                         s,
                                         nil]]; 
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: It is the second option I needed! I love you :D

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` is an ordered collection of objects. It is not a key-value mapping of objects. Calling `setValue:forKey:` on an `NSArray` is the same as sending `setValue:forKey:` to each of its items.

Answer (score 1):

This setValue:ForKey: method is not from the NSMutableArray, it is [NSKeyValueCodingProtocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

In your case, since you want ordered results from a dictionary, you could take a look at the following methods:

– keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:
– keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:
– keysSortedByValueWithOptions:usingComparator:

If you need values sorted, just use allKeys which returns an array. You can them sort the array using any of the following methods:

– sortedArrayHint
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:
– sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:hint:
– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
– sortedArrayUsingSelector:
– sortedArrayUsingComparator:
– sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator:

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to store an ordered list of pairs.  So NSArray of NSArrays

```
for (NSString *s in array)
{
    NSRange ran = [s rangeOfString:@"abc"];
    if (ran.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        int inde = [array indexOfObject:s];
        NSArray* pair = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:inde],s,nil];
        [mutarray addObject: pair];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what Darren's second option looks like, except you made a NSMutableArray of two NSArrays.